# Update Workflow Task from an external webpart

Tags: development, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I have a sequential workflow which creates a task that contains the custom url to a custom webpart.

The web part provides the option to select different statuses. When the user selects 'Approved' I want to mark the respective task as completed.

How can I get this done in c#?

Answer (score 2):

you can get the idea from the code below

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername/");
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
  SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];
  SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(22);
  SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[0];
  SPWorkflowTask task = workflow.Tasks[0];

  Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();       
  ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
  ht["Completed"] = "TRUE";
  ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
  ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
  ht["Status"] = "Completed";
  ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)task.Web.Language, false), Strings.WorkflowStatusCompleted, new object[0]);
  ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = "Approved";
  ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";
  ht["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.Completed;

  web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
  SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((task as SPListItem), ht, true);
}
```

Source [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0b915df7-6cef-4121-ba2d-999662659a27/approve-workflow-task-programatically)

Comment: @Rami-shareef I tried the same with a SharePoint 2013 workflow, It dint work. I am gettin an argument out of range exception in item.Workflows[0]. Do you have any ideas on that?